# Call to action are not working inside scrollable sections of fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I've embedded fullpage.js in my page and on the sections which have scroll in it, Links, submit buttons and checkboxes doesn't seems to be working in it.
I tried putting an alert on click of a link for testing

```
$('.project-image').click(function(){
        alert('hola')
    })
```

even this simple thing is not working and there is no error on console.
it looks like something is preventing clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I figured it out.
after removing switch case: a.preventDefault(); from handleEvent: function(a) from the file scrolloverflow.js all the links are working now.
I was freaking out before so for others I am attaching the sample code for reference.

```
handleEvent: function(a) {
        switch (a.type) {
            case "touchstart":
            case "pointerdown":
            case "MSPointerDown":
            case "mousedown":
                this._start(a);
                break;
            case "touchmove":
            case "pointermove":
            case "MSPointerMove":
            case "mousemove":
                this._move(a);
                break;
            case "touchend":
            case "pointerup":
            case "MSPointerUp":
            case "mouseup":
            case "touchcancel":
            case "pointercancel":
            case "MSPointerCancel":
            case "mousecancel":
                this._end(a);
                break;
            case "orientationchange":
            case "resize":
                this._resize();
                break;
            case "transitionend":
            case "webkitTransitionEnd":
            case "oTransitionEnd":
            case "MSTransitionEnd":
                this._transitionEnd(a);
                break;
            case "wheel":
            case "DOMMouseScroll":
            case "mousewheel":
                this._wheel(a);
                break;
            case "keydown":
                this._key(a);
                break;
            case "click":
                this.enabled && !a._constructed && (a.preventDefault(), a.stopPropagation())
        }
    }
```

Just remove the last case "click"

Comment: You don't need to modify the scrolloverflow.js file. Just make sure you are using the latest fullpage.js version 2.8.1 and it should work as expected on desktops.